# How can i post data to specific database in restful ravendb

Tags: c#, rest, ravendb, ravendb-http

Consider this code:

```
      HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = 
    httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://logger/RavenDB/docs/MdbLogger", 
new { Content = log.Content + i, Id = i, test = "" }).Result;
```

when send request without MdbLogger all thing is ok. But when send the request with MdbLogger i get 400 http response.

> Could not figure out what to do Your request didn't match anything
>
> that Raven knows to do, sorry...

How can i post data to specific database in restful ravendb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for calling a specific db is:

```
http://logger/RavenDB/databases/MdbLogger/docs
```

In general, the path is always the same, but it starts with `/databases/db-name`